# UserManager.CreateAsync .Success always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to add users programmatically to the AspNetUsers table in my ASP.Net MVC 5.0 app using the following function:

```
private async Task AddUser(DataImportMember member)
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser
    {
        UserName = member.Email,
        Email = member.Email,
        UserType = UserType.IsMember
    };

    var password = RandomPassword.Generate();
    var result = await this.UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, MyApp.IsMember);
    }
}
```

But whenever I call `this.UserManager.CreateAsync`, `result.Succeed` is always false. I've checked the AspNetUsers table and as expected, the user is not added.

Any ideas how I can figure out what's wrong and how to resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: check the result error message to find out why the save failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UserManager.CreateAsync` returns an `IdentityResult` that would also contain any errors why the action was not successful. You should check the result error messages to find out why the action failed.

```
var result = await this.UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
if (result.Succeeded) {
    await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, MyApp.IsMember);
} else {
    var errors = result.Errors;
    var message = string.Join(", ", errors);
    ModelState.AddModelError("", message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi. Feel stupid that I didn't think of looking into what obviously was an object. I just looked at the `.Succeed`. Anyway, problem solved. Had 2 different connection strings defined and was only clearing one of database. All sorted anyway. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

You can put try catch for checking the actual error.

```
   try{
        var result = await this.UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
    }
    catch(exception ex)
    {
     through ex;
    }
```

After getting the exact error it will be better to remove the try catch block.